# Pull Strings Before and After Key Words

Tags: sas

Not sure if this possible in SAS; although I'm slowly learning pretty much anything is possible in SAS...

I have a data-set of 600 patients and within that data-set I have a comment variable. The comment variable contains a few sentences each patient stated about his/her care. So for example, the data set looks like this:

```
 ID        Comment
 1         Today we have great service. everyone was really nice.
 2         The customer service team did not know what they were talking about and was rude.
 3         Everyone was very helpful 5 stars.
 4         Not very helpful at all.
 5         Staff was nice.
 6         All the people was really nice.
```

Lets say I identify a number of key words I'm interested in; for example nice, rude and helpful.

Is there a way to pull 2 strings that come before these words and produce a frequency table?

```
 WORD            Frequency 
 Was Really Nice         2
 And Was Rude            1
 Was Very Helpful        1
 Not very helpful        1
```

I have a code written already which will help me to identify the key words, this code creates a count of the freq of each word within the comment variable.

```
 data PG_2 / view=PG_2;
 length word $20;
 set PG_1;
 do i = 1 by 1 until(missing(word));
 word = upcase(scan(COMMENT, i));
 if not missing(word) then output;
 end;
 keep word;
 run;

 proc freq data=PG_2 order=freq;
 table word / out=wordfreq(drop=percent);
 run;
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the perl regular expression ([PRX](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p06i7305izsnvcn1ru9147suzyv5.htm&docsetVersion=3.1&locale=en)) functions in SAS. I think they might solve your issue.

You can use RegEx capture groups to pull out the two words directly before your keyword using `prxparse` and `prxposn`. The below should grab any two words before the word nice in the comment variable and add them to the `firstTwoStrings` variable.

```
data firstTwoStrings;
   length firstTwoStrings $200;
   retain re;
   if _N_ = 1 then
      re = prxparse('/(\w+ \w+) nice/'); /*change 'nice' to your desired keyword*/
   set comments;
   if prxmatch(re, COMMENT) then 
      do;
         firstTwoStrings = prxposn(re, 1, COMMENT);
      end;
run;
```

Comment: Or use the following to search for all interesting words at once
'/(\w+ \w+ (nice|rude|helpful))/' Also consider using prxnext for multiple hits in one string

Comment: @Ben_Corcoran thanks this looks great, going to test this out now! Sorry about not responding sooner - as soon as I posted this I came down with the stomach bug and was out of commission for the past 3 days.